# Вращение точки по окружности

Tags: javascript

Собственно, вопрос такой, как найти координаты точки на окружности зная радиус и угол?

Comment: Удивительно, но я провел в гугле минут 40 прежде чем пойти сюда

Answer (score 3):

Задача сводится к поиску сторон прямоугольного треугольника при известной гипотенузе (радиус ) и всех углах (одного угла правда достаточно).

Координаты определются как:

- x = R * cos(A)
- y = R * sin(A)

Осталось правильно выбрать систему координат (точнее преобразование с декартовой в экранную).